# Jump to a specific part of a page in a moodle wiki?

Tags: moodle, wiki

I should create a moodle wiki and I have got some sections on my wiki-page. Now I would like to create a table of contents where The user can jump between the sections like on Wikipedia.

What I tried:

```
<a href="#section1">section1</a>
...
<h2 id="section1">Section1</h2>
```

The problem I got is that when I save the page the id property will be removed from the tags

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the latest version of Moodle, it is possible to make the HTML ids stick if you add you HTML markups within the Wiki **HTML editor**.

This has to be the ultimate change you do to the document. Once you have your HTML correctly tagged, directly hit the **Save** button without going back to the editor's preview mode. They should be available in the Wiki after that.

If you need to edit the page again, be sure to **keep a local copy of your HTML structure**, in order to avoid having to add the HTML markups again. They will be removed everytime you edit the page or if you switch from the HTML editor to the WYSIWYG preview mode.